# Anyone ever heard of something being above discussion?

Tags: meaning, idiom-requests

Has anyone ever heard of the phrase, "that is something above discussion"?

It came to mind today, but I couldn't find anything over the Internet. Maybe it sounds like that, but is something else, in fact, the way the words of a song can go misheard.

The meaning I expected it would be is when something has been decided out of another's reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sounds like you've misremembered [beyond dispute](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/beyond-dispute):

> impossible to disagree with
>
> *The main part of his argument was beyond dispute.*

Answer (score 2):

[**nondebatable**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/undebatable) or **non-debatable**: not able to be debated.

[collinsdictionary.com]

Answer (score 0):

it's **beyond recall**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beyond+recall)

**impossible to change, reverse, retrieve, or restore.**

Answer (score 0):

If A is above B (*discussion* in this case), typically in a specific context, it means that there is no scope of using B on A. This is like discussion (in the sense of debate) is not encouraged on a gospel which is an established/respected notion (especially within specific contexts).

ODO:

> **[above](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/above)**
>   *PREPOSITION*
>   **2.2** Considered of higher status or worth than; **too good for**.
>
> ‘She wants her actions, inactions, and mistakes to be above any legal
>   reproach.’

MW:

> **[above](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/above)**
>   *preposition*
>   **2 b** : out of reach of
>   *'above suspicion'*

Comment: Beyond dispute is not what I was looking for, but it is a good substitute. There is a slim chance I used to use this expression not knowing it was a false translation; or was just not putting it right.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idiom you were thinking of is

**[out of the question](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/italiano-inglese/questo-%C3%A8-fuori-discussione)**

If  something is out of the question, you are saying it is totally unacceptable and it is
**not [up for discussion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up%20for%20discussion)**, the speaker is categorically affirming that the request is impossible to meet and it is unthinkable that it will be permitted. 
It translates the Italian idiom "fuori discussione" which a poor translator tool might have translated it as: out = *above* or *out* of *discussion*.

> It is out of the question for a twelve-year-old to go to a nightclub!